# Azure Timer Function connection limits

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure Trimer function that executes every 15 minutes. The function compiles data from 3 data sources, WCF service, REST endpoint and Table Storage, and insert the data into CosmosDb. Where I am running into an issues is that after 7 or 8 executions of function I get the "Host thresholds exceeded: [Connections]" error. Here is what is really strange, the function takes about 2 minutes to execute. The error doesn't show in the logs until well after the function is done executing.

I have gone through all the connection limits documentation and understand it. Where I am a bit confused is when the limits matter. A single execution of my function does not come anywhere close to hitting the 600 active connection limit. **Do the connection limits apply to the individual execution of the timer function or are the limits an cumulative over multiple executions?**

Here is the real kicker, this function was running fine for two weeks until 07/22/2012. Nothing in the code has changed and it has not been redeployed.

Runtime is 3.1.3

Answer (score 0):

Is your function on a Consumption Plan or in an App Service Plan?

From your description it just sounds like your code may be leaking connections and building up a large number of them over time.

Maybe this blog post can help in ensuring the right usage patterns? https://4lowtherabbit.github.io/blogs/2019/10/SNAT/